# psycopg2 connect error: cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to pass json object as argument to my stored procedure. I tried many things and solved couple of error atlast I am stuck with this erro "psycopg2 connect error: cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function" i tried json.dumps where it gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpsqB.png) ..  if i am executing from scripts with same input it works fine. below is my stored procedure..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.insert_usr_details_in_all_tables (jsonobject json)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
skill_s  Text[] := '{}';
    selectedSkill TEXT;
    edu TEXT;
    email TEXT;
    phone TEXT;
    usr_name TEXT;
    clg TEXT;
    lstEmployer TEXT;
    gendr TEXT;
    skill_row_count  INTEGER;
    usr_id INTEGER;
    skl_id INTEGER;
    intEmailExist INTEGER;
    expen DECIMAL;
BEGIN

    -- Getting name
    SELECT jsonobject->'Name' into usr_name;
    
    -- Getting education
    SELECT jsonobject->'Education' into edu;
    
    -- Getting phone number
    SELECT jsonobject->'phone_number' into phone;
    
    -- Getting experience
    SELECT (jsonobject->>'Exp')::DECIMAL INTO expen;
    
    --Getting college
    SELECT jsonobject->'College' into clg;
    
    
    -- Getting last employer
    SELECT jsonobject->'CurrentEmployer' into lstEmployer;
    
    --Getting gender
    SELECT jsonobject->'Gender' into gendr;
    
    -- Getting Email
    SELECT json_array_length(jsonobject->'Email') into intEmailExist;
    IF intEmailExist > 0 THEN 
        email:=array(SELECT json_array_elements_text(jsonobject->'Email'));
    END IF;
    
    -- Insert user details in 'Extractor_usr_details' table.
    INSERT INTO public."Extractor_usr_details"(name, phone_number, email, exp, education, college, "currentEmployer", gender)VALUES ( usr_name, phone, email, expen, edu, clg, lstEmployer, gendr) returning "id" into usr_id;
    
    skill_s := array(SELECT json_array_elements_text(jsonObject->'Skills'));
    FOREACH selectedSkill IN ARRAY skill_s LOOP
        INSERT INTO public."Extractor_skills" (skill) SELECT selectedSkill WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM public."Extractor_skills" WHERE skill = selectedSkill)RETURNING id into skl_id;
        INSERT INTO public."Extractor_usr_skills" (skill_id, user_id) SELECT skl_id, usr_id WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM public."Extractor_usr_skills" WHERE skill_id = skl_id AND user_id = usr_id);
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
$BODY$;
```

and here is my code to call the stored procedure in python  project

```
    try:
        # declare a new PostgreSQL connection object
        conn = connect(
            dbname="postgres",
            user="postgres",
            host="localhost",
            password="demo",
            port= '5432'
            # attempt to connect for 3 seconds then raise exception
        )
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.callproc('insert_usr_details_in_all_tables', json.dumps(jsonObject))


    except (Exception) as err:
        print("\npsycopg2 connect error:", err)
        conn = None
        cur = None
```